# New notice banners

Tags: discussion, support

From I have found that new notice banners have started appearing on questions. Some examples are:

[image]

[image]

But what was the reason for this new look? Why aren't they question closed as homework and exercise type show the specific reason? Any other relevant information are welcomed here!

Comment: [New Post Notices are live network-wide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339700/), on the Mother Meta, has the details and links to the previous discussions.

Comment: In particular, [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/339733/184688) on that thread asks about the sub-reasons for off-topic closures.

Comment: Pretty much every question about network UI should be posted on Mother Meta.

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned in the comments, the status and reasons for this change are discussed in detail in the thread [New Post Notices are live network-wide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339700/new-post-notices-are-live-network-wide) on Meta Stack Exchange, as well as the linked blog posts and mother-meta threads.

In particular, [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/339733/184688) raises the specific complaint that the new off-topic closures don't show the specific closure sub-reason text which documents why the question was closed and which links to the site's further guidance about what to do in those scenarios, which **absolutely, definitely breaks one of the key mechanisms of that this site has to communicate its scope to newcomers.**

That answer is marked, as of this writing, as [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) by the SE dev team. Support of that answer (via votes on the answer and its comments, as well as civil, well-argued comments for why it's important) is probably the best (only?) way to make this change and change quickly.

Comment: Eg, the answerer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/518536/123208) is a new member, and cannot see the custom close reason, and is likely upset that their correct answer is getting downvotes. If their answer does get deleted I hope an explanatory comment is posted.